# Formula to increment by volume and issue number, each in sets of three

Tags: excel, integer, excel-formula, worksheet-function, modulus

I have journal articles which contain three issues per volume.

Is there a formula to increment 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 and then jump to 2.1, 2.2, 2.3?

Comment: Increment where, and based on what?  Do you just want a formula you can fill down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Row3 please try:

```
=INT(ROW()/3)&"."&MOD(ROW(),3)+1
```

and copy down to suit. For other rows you would need to add an offset (`+n`).